# `hostname` - host name or FQDN?

Tags: networking, hostname

What is the right thing to set a computer's hostname to? (`/bin/hostname`, `/etc/hostname`, `sethostname(2)`, etc.)

I usually just use the "name" part, and it works perfectly (for me at least), but I've seen it implied in some places that I should use the entire "name.domain.tld" instead... which just doesn't feel "right" for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just the name as you already do. A hostname shouldn't contain any domainname.